# Fatal error: Function name must be a string whilst it shouldn't

Tags: php, arrays, string, fatal-error

I have stumbled over the following error in PHP:

> "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   F:\Applications\xampp\htdocs\BTB_Sandbox\uploads.php on line 15"

and I don't know what the real problem is. Here is line 15 that the error is pointing at:

```
$error = $_FILES(['file_upload']['error']);
```

I hope you could help me, because I am kind of stuck now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$_FILES` as a function because of ().
That way, PHP tries to call a function named as var `$_FILES` value, but this value it not a string (that's the error reported), it is an array.

Obviously, in your code line you are failing to use `$_FILES`, the right way is:

```
$error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!